# Use guid to register instance of xamarin forms app

Tags: xamarin.forms

Good day fellow code ninjas,
I am attempting to make my Xamarin forms application be device unique in the sense that you are not able to login with your credentials on any device other than the one you initially installed the application on.

I have deduced that I should be using a guid for this purpose. I have searched online but I'm not able to find much of a guide on how exactly to use a guid to recognize a specific device.

Are there perhaps any resources related to this or any examples of code used to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few layers to this question, firstly:

## Can I Uniquely Identify A Device? No

You won't be able to get truly uniquely identifying information about the device such as UDID, IMEI. This is enforced by the platforms (iOS & Android) as a way of protecting users sensitive information.

This process is called Fingerprinting. There are 2 cases that the platforms want to avoid: Advertisers tracking users across apps, Malicious use of unique id's to target a user. In older versions of iOS & Android there were more API's to use to uniquely identify a user but they are being phased out as privacy & security have become greater concerns for mobile users.

## What Are My Options?

Lets accept that we can never truly uniquely identify a device, there are some tricks we can use.

### Secure Storage

You can generate a guid and place it in secure storage on the devices keychain. This keychain value can be persisted even if your app is uninstalled. You could use this approach to check if the app is unique to the user. There are pitfalls with this approach, it's not perfect but it's the approach myself and many other's use.

It is worth mentioning the behaviour across devices is very inconsistent. The iOS keychain can be backed up to iCloud (if encryption is enabled). Android devices can use slightly different standards across API levels & vendors.

### iOS - identifierForVendor

iOS will generate a guid when you install an app, you can use this value instead of generating your own. See the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidevice/1620059-identifierforvendor).

The 2 drawbacks here are you'd need to implement this on a platform level and if they user deletes all of your apps, the guid gets deleted and a new one is generated when they reinstall the app:

> The value in this property remains the same while the app (or another app from the same vendor) is installed on the iOS device. The value changes when the user deletes all of that vendor’s apps from the device and subsequently reinstalls one or more of them. The value can also change when installing test builds using Xcode or when installing an app on a device using ad-hoc distribution. Therefore, if your app stores the value of this property anywhere, you should gracefully handle situations where the identifier changes.

---

Edit 1:
Add further clarification: Explain fingerprinting & highlight some platform nuances

Comment: Thank you for the clear comprehensive answer. This helps a lot!

Comment: I've updated the info a little as I remembered this practise is called fingerprinting.